# Meteor - Custom Deployment

Tags: meteor

I have deployed my Meteor Application on my local machine using:

https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

Now during the process I used:

`$ export ROOT_URL='http://192.168.100.2:9000'`

Now my is not accessible on `http://192.168.100.2:9000`, but instead it is accessible on `http://192.168.100.2:46223`, so every time I do node main.js, it choose some random port for my application.

How can I specify a port of my own choice here?

Answer (score 2):

You should also supply the `PORT` environment variable to instruct the app which port to listen on, as it is not inferred from the `ROOT_URL`. It is also not necessarily the same, as apps may have a reverse proxy in front of them.

See [the official documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#PORT) for more environment variables.